# Driven-damped oscillator: deduce the phase and/or resonant freq from amplitudes at varying freqs

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

Suppose that we have a fairly standard driven-damped harmonic oscillator (i.e. linear spring restoring force, linear damping force, sinusoidal driving force, etc).

The catch is: we don't know the phase of the driving force. We can vary its frequency (and the amplitude of the driving force depends upon the frequency and is known), however.

The question is: is it possible to make a series of observations of the *resulting* amplitude of the oscillation of the mass and then deduce either the resonant frequency of the oscillator or what the phase-shift (from that observed for the mass) is for any of the given driving frequencies?

In other words, suppose that I have the following inputs to the oscillator:

F<sub>1</sub> = A<sub>F1</sub> * sin( ω<sub>1</sub> )
F<sub>2</sub> = A<sub>F2</sub> * sin( ω<sub>2</sub> )
F<sub>3</sub> = A<sub>F3</sub> * sin( ω<sub>3</sub> )
...

and then I observe some motion of the mass, described as:

x<sub>1</sub> = A<sub>x1</sub> * sin( ω<sub>1</sub> + φ<sub>unk1</sub> )
x<sub>2</sub> = A<sub>x2</sub> * sin( ω<sub>2</sub> + φ<sub>unk2</sub> )
x<sub>3</sub> = A<sub>x3</sub> * sin( ω<sub>3</sub> + φ<sub>unk3</sub> )
...

What I want is to be able to figure out what φ<sub>unk</sub> is for any of the observations, if I know all of the A<sub>x n</sub>'s. You can also assume that we know all of the *differences* between φ<sub>unk1</sub>, φ<sub>unk2</sub>, and φ<sub>unk3</sub>. In other words, we know how the phase of the mass' oscillation is *changing*; we just don't know how its related to the driving force.

Now, I'm aware that:

tan( φ ) = ( ω<sub>0</sub><sup>2</sup> - ω<sup>2</sup> ) / 2ω<sub>0</sub>ωζ

Where ζ is a damping constant and ω<sub>0</sub> is the resonant frequency. However, I'm unable to leverage this into a analytical solution.

Note: If you need to assume that the various test frequencies are either *all below* or *all above* the resonant frequency, then go ahead.

Comment: Yes, but... see Kramers-Kronig: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations

Comment: "...is it possible to make a series of observations of the resulting amplitude of the oscillation of the mass and then deduce either the resonant frequency of the oscillator..." Sure, just fit the Lorentzian line shape.